# How to use the ajax toolkit in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

Hi I have installed the AJAX Toolkit by following [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/07/ajax-control-tookit-installation-in-visual-web-developer.aspx) but I don't know how to use the controls of AJAX in ASP.Net. I tried [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) tutorial but this gave me some errors.

Comment: Which control in particular are you trying to use.? What errors are you getting and can you post your markup?

Comment: What errors are happening? Put your code.

Comment: please dont say that you just dropped it in there and hoped it would work lol

Comment: Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload'. this error is occuring while i make a build solution

Comment: Have you add control ref in page directive

Comment: May help http://forums.asp.net/post/5135705.aspx

Comment: yes, but still the error is the same

Comment: @PiLHA, this leads me to the new error that is "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies."

Comment: @user2384794 you probably did not install correctly AjaxToolkit is missing references. Your aspx has a reference to ajax? Something like this <% @ Register Assembly = "AjaxControlToolkit, Version = 3.5.60501.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace = "AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix = "AjaxControlToolkit"%>

Comment: yes, it right after the page directives

Answer (score 0):

Download from here the latest version of ajax toolkit

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Inside this zip, you find one more zip file called "AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite.zip", uncompress it and you find all possible examples with source code fully running.